# Laravel 8.x - Filtering users based on roles when a user have multiple roles

Tags: laravel

I am working on a project in which a user will have multiple roles. I am kind of clueless on how to tackle this situation. Currently , I have a `users` table and a roles table

[[image: Roles table1]

I have also created a pivot table `user_roles` which adds roles for a user

[image: user_roles table]

I have added belongsToMany clause in the users table.

```
  public function roles() {
        //return $this->hasMany(EventUser::class);

        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'portal_user_roles', 'user_id', 'role_id')->withTimestamps();
    }
```

I need to fetch the users based on their role. The role id will be passed from the frontend.

Can you please suggest a way i can find the users matching a particular role?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Role model you also need `users()` relationship

```
// Role model

public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'user_roles');
}
```

Then in your controller, when you have `$roleId`, you can get the role and its users.

```
$role = Role::find($roleId);
$role->users;
```

PS. not sure about your pivot table name, you referred to as `user_roles` but in your code it's `portal_user_roles`

Answer (score 2):

first of all define a relation in your user model.

```php
  public function users() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

then in your controller you can write

```php
$users = Role::findOrFail($request->role_id)->users;
```

done

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to define the relationship on the role direction and get the users that way (which you should it makes more sense I think) you can do this on the user's side:

```
$roleId = 15; // Or whatever
$usersWithRole15 = Users::whereHas('roles', function ($query) use ($roleId) {
    $query->where('id', $roleId);
})->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting all users that have a role, first, define your relationships in your Models(Role & User):

Role Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Role extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'foreign_key', 'role_id');
    }
}
?>
```

User Model:

```
<?php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class User extends Model
{
    public function role() {
        return $this->belongsTo(Role::class);
    }
}
?>
```

In your view just call the user method that you have created in your Role Model:

```
@if($roles)
    @foreach($roles AS $role)
        @if($role->user)
            @foreach($role->user AS $user)
                {{ $user->id.": ".$user->title }}
            @endforeach
        @endif
    @endforeach
@endif
```